# Filter graph nodes that have a connection with a candidate

Tags: javascript, graph-theory

I'd like to `filter` a list so that I'd get only the nodes that have a connection, either *direct* or *indirect* with a candidate

```
  var candidate = 1;
  var data = [
    { source: 1, target: 2 }, // is connected with 1
    { source: 2, target: 3 }, // is connected with 1
    { source: 6, target: 9 }, // no connection
    { source: 12, target: 15 }, // no connection
    { source: 3, target: 2 }, // is connected with 1
    { source: 5, target: 3 }, // is connected with 1
  ]
```

What kind of algorithm am I looking for?

The language of interest is JavaScript - AFAIK some languages would implement an algorithm in a different way than others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breadth-First Search:

Maintain a list of "Maybe" edges (initialized with the given list), a list of "Connected" edges (initialized empty) and a list of nodes (initialized to contain only the "candidate").

Remove a node from the node list.
Iterate through the Maybe list, looking for that node; if an edge contains that node, copy the other node into the node list and move that edge into the Connected list.
Continue until the node list is empty.

Comment: `Remove a node from the node list.` Do you mean the maybe list? The node list would initially contain just the candidate

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides: No, I mean the node list. It will initially contain only the candidate; remove that one and iterate through the Maybe list, looking for that node. If, at the end of that, the node list is empty, then you're done: none of the edges are connected to the candidate.